# Possible to attach a .Zip file to Jenkins after a Build has Completed?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

1. Possible to attach a .Zip file to Jenkins after a Build has Completed?

*Scenario:*

1. I have 20 tests which get executed.
2. Once the tests and the build has completed.
3. A zip file will then get created storing all test results.

**4. Is it possible to attach a .zip file to a build after a build has completed?**

thanks for your help

Comment: Attach a .zip as another parameter for a trigged post built-action job, or should the .zip be published somewhere?

Comment: @Xry thanks for the comment, the file dosnt need to be published anywhere after each build the .zip file just needs to be attached to the build. for example Test1 executes > build1 now has the .zip file of results attatched, build2 executes and the latest/updated .zip file is now attached to build2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the Email-ext plugin [`https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin`](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)

In the Attachments section, as it says,  "Can use wildcards like 'module/dist/**/*.zip'"